# Contract equivalence check in certora

Tags: certora

I have two contracts in solidity:

```js
contract A{
  uint256 public number = 0;
  function addOne() public {
    number = number + 1;
  }
}

contract B{
  uint256 public number = 0;
  function addOne() public {
    number = 1 + number;
  }
}
```

And I want to prove that no matter what, if each contract starts with the same input, they will have the same output state.

How would I make this rule in certora?

### Context

I was thinking something like this:

Here is what I have so far:

```js
rule calling_any_function_should_result_in_each_contract_having_the_same_state(method f, method f2){
    env e;
    calldataarg args;
    
    require(a.number == b.number);
    require(f.selector == f2.selector);

    a.f(e, args);
    b.f2(e, args);

    assert(a.number() == b.number());
}
```

But... Certora is telling me doing something like this is vascus.

Answer (score 1):

The vacuity here makes sense since you're asking the Prover to prove `number + 1 == 1 + number`  which ones simplified is the same as asking the Prover to prove `assert(true)`. The vacuity here is not problematic in my opinion as you're checking gas optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

I played with the spec and had to add a `require` assumption that both contracts start with the same number value. Otherwise, the Prover was coming up with an initial state with different numbers even though the sol code initializes them both at 0 and despite [calling each function `at initial` state after declaring `storage initial = lastStorage;`](https://docs.certora.com/en/latest/docs/cvl/types.html?highlight=laststorage#the-storage-type).

Note the approach could be refactored to [compare entire contracts’ storage](https://youtu.be/Gle2-dB2m94?si=j9mW-T9oHIB1hWCZ&t=1722) as opposed to just the number values.

Here’s my current code:

```
using A as a;
using B as b;

methods
{
    function a.number() external returns(uint256) envfree;
    function b.number() external returns(uint256) envfree;
}

rule calling_any_function_should_result_in_each_contract_having_the_same_state(method f, method f2) {
    storage initial = lastStorage;
    env e; calldataarg args;

    require(a.number() == b.number());
    require(f.selector == f2.selector);

    a.f(e, args) at initial;
    mathint a_result = a.number();
    
    b.f2(e, args) at initial;
    mathint b_result = b.number();

    assert(a_result == b_result);
}
```

```
contract A {
    uint256 public number = 0;
    function addOne() public {
        number = number + 1;
    }
}
```

```
contract B {
    uint256 public number = 0;
    function addOne() public {
        number = 1 + number;
    }
}
```

[Run report link without basic sanity](https://prover.certora.com/output/363702/c9f9eb6a2e3f4c2b82ab09f23bacbbd1/?anonymousKey=b85509c10bd1d804fece2bbf7fb3dfcff4c18888).

[Run report link with basic sanity](https://prover.certora.com/output/363702/f1c6d22365fb4df8b32b616c8fe174fb/?anonymousKey=c0043f8b4d2ddfb82cc76dd8a83e297cd0e7f414) (vacuous finding).

Command: `certoraRun A.sol B.sol --verify A:calling_any.spec` (--rule_sanity basic)

I’m just a beginner in CVL so maybe someone else can comment on a better solution.